# JPA: How to check NULL query-parameter value with HQL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
Query query =  em.createQuery(
        "select count(u) from User u where (u.id=:a) and (u.photo=:b)")
        .setParameter("a",userId).setParameter("b",null);
```

In my case, I want check whether user photo uploaded or not (photo value is null or not).
I tried above query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [example in Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where).

You should check is parameter is null:

```
Query query =  em.createQuery(
        "select count(u) from User u where (u.id=:userId) and (u.photo is null)")
        .setParameter("userId",userId);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're aiming at generalising "b", so that a method can receive either a given search value, or a null, this usually works:

```
Query q = em.createQuery (
  "SELECT ... WHERE ... ( :b IS NULL AND u.photo IS NULL OR u.photo = :b )" 
);
q.setParameter ( "b", searchValue ); // can be null
...
```

There is an helper to use this approach [here](https://github.com/marco-brandizi/jUtils/blob/master/jutils-j2ee/src/main/java/uk/ac/ebi/utils/sql/HqlUtils.java) (see parameterizedWithNullHql()).